# SMPS output is 11.3v, Whether required 12v

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

My problem regarding my computer is that, when i am trying to start my computer with a faulty SMPS ( is the output voltage faulty? : +11.3v, -11.3v, +5v, +3.3v) it is not even switched on as well as SMPS fan is not running. In the other hand with a new SMPS, computer is running with out any trouble. output of the new SMPS is : +12v, -12v, +5v, +3.3v.
  Please reply to solve the problem or to repair the SMPS.

Comment: Do **not open** a SMPS. It contains parts with **lethal voltages** even when not connected to mains for a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

*Please reply to solve the problem or to repair the SMPS.*

Buy a new power supply.

Computer power supplies are cheap and available.  The chances of fixing one without proper documentation is small, and messing it up could cause serious damage to your computer.  Think of these power supplies as indivisible replacable units.  Don't screw around inside them.

Answer (score 1):

**Please do not open the cover unless you have professional training in working on high voltage devices. Seriously.**

However, when you are looking for hints what may be wrong with your power supply, here's what you can do without opening the cover: *Use an oscilloscope and measure the output voltages during start-up and during operation.* You may have a power supply with output capacitors degraded over time (i.e. less capacitance than the new devices), causing excessive ripple or start-up problems. *Using a DC voltmeter alone will not be enough to give you the required information.*

**Again: Opening your power supply is very dangerous. High voltages remain in the input capacitors even if you disconnect the input cable! The stored energy is potentially lethal.**